# How do I store an image in MySQL database using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to store an image in a MySQL database with the use of PHP. What is the datatype that I should use?

Comment: Datatype should be blob, but I would recommend storing images in a file system and only it's path in the DB table. Another great option is to use Amazon s3 buckets.

Comment: Some folks store the image itself in a directory and then store the filepath in the database, which I think is the best approach. If the pictures are small (like icons or what-have-you) you could convert the file's binary to Base64 and store that string in the database, as another option. You could also toss the binary into a `blob` type. Lots of viable options, you just have to figure out what works best for your requirements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can store the base64 string of the image in your table.

```
$img_file = "/tmp/my_image.jpg";
// get base64 string
$imgData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($img_file));

// insert into DB
$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO my_image_table (img_base64) VALUES(?)");
$dbh->execute(array($imgData));
```

Make sure your data type of the column is big enough for the images. LONGTEXT can save up to 4GB.

Alternative: use BLOB or file-paths like others suggested.