HY000 General error 1366 Incorrect string value in MySQL MEDIUMBLOB
I am tring to insert image data into a mediumblob column on a table in my database.  The image data was retrieved via file_get_contents($imageURL) ;
When I attempt to update the table (which previously had no images at all - the column is new), I get an error:
 (HY000,1366,Incorrect string value: '\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE0\x00\x10...' for column 'newImage' at row 1)

on this merged statement (actually it's a prepared statement; these are the effective values:
WITH newValues AS ( SELECT 'UCmwUfKjS6zDt_kHTTMw9Rig' AS channelId 
                         , <data> AS newImage 
                         , 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/yada/yada' AS newImageURL
                    )
UPDATE AuthorChannels ac
JOIN   newValues nv
    ON ac.channel_id = nv.channelId
SET ac.image = nv.newImage 
  , ac.imageURL = nv.newImageURL
WHERE ac.image != nv.newImage
   OR COALESCE(ac.imageURL, '') <> COALESCE(nv.newImageURL, '') ;

I am a little confused how this data can be invalid in any MySQL BLOB.  What might I do in order to correct this?
PHP code is like this:
$newImage = (empty($img_url) ? '' : @file_get_contents($img_url)) ;
$authorChannelValues = [  'channelId' => $channelId
                        , 'image' => empty($newImage) ? NULL : $newImage
                        , 'imgurl' => empty($img_url) ? NULL : $img_url
                            ] ;
$ok = $insertAuthorChannel->execute($authorChannelValues) ;

Original SQL statement:
WITH newValues AS (
         SELECT :channelId AS channelId
              , :image AS newImage
              , :imgurl AS newImageURL
         )
UPDATE AuthorChannels ac
JOIN   newValues nv
    ON ac.channel_id = nv.channelId
SET    ac.image = nv.newImage
     , ac.imageURL = nv.newImageURL
WHERE  ac.image != nv.newImage
    OR COALESCE(ac.imageURL, '') <> COALESCE(nv.newImageURL, '')

Here is the table layout:
mysql> describe AuthorChannels;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| channel_id        | varchar(32)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| firstChatEpoch    | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lastChatEpoch     | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| chatCount         | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| firstCommentEpoch | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lastCommentEpoch  | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| commentCount      | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| doNotList         | tinyint      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| image             | mediumblob   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| imageURL          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


That error makes me think ac.image is actually MEDIUMTEXT, not MEDIUMBLOB. I tested and I can reproduce the error if image is MEDIUMTEXT. Can you please query SHOW CREATE TABLE AuthorChannels and verify the column data type?

I agree with you @BillKarwin , surprises me too.  But I've now put the description of the table (from the horse's mouth, as they say) into the question.  The column type is mediumblob.

Okay, I have no suggestions. As I said, I tested using MySQL 8.0.39 and I cannot reproduce this unless I change the column to MEDIUMTEXT. A binary column should not complain about incorrect strings, but a text column has a character set and therefore may not accept certain sequences of bytes that do not correspond to any encoding in that character set (for example, UTF8 does not have any character beginning with the byte 0xFF). So either your code is not updating the table you think it is, or you aren't using MySQL, or some other mystery.

The error message refers to column newImage, while the table you showed has column called image, but no newImage. newImahe seems to be a column from the other table.

@Shadow yes, I don't know what to make of that.  MySQL should treat it as untyped data, similarly to the BLOB.  As you can see, newImage is from the Context Table Expression listed , beginning with WITH ...  It is defined solely by the context of the WITH clause

Thwre is no such thing as untyped data in mysql. It is clearly treated is text data resulting in an error. You wrote the file's contents are passed via prepared statement from php. You indicated you used file_get_contents() to read the file's content. That function returns a string, so it is passed as a string to mysql and there you go. Perhaps playing around with connection character set could help or place _binary before the placeholder to indicate the string is binary

I found the trick (base64_encode(...)) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73477958/how-do-i-store-an-image-in-mysql-database-using-php
